# http://www.givenow.com.au/ Whats is this site written in?

Tags: programming-languages

I want to know what this site is written in?
Does anyone know please?
And yes I dont know much about creating websites so thats why I give it to someone else to do.
Just wanted to know what the above site is written in please?
Matt

Comment: Do a browser source code look up. It will tell you the JavaScript libraries being used. But as @Simon mentioned a website is created mostly using HTML and CSS with JavaScript mixed in to handle client-side interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the field names for the login form (`j_username` and `j_password`), I'm going to guess they're using Spring Security for authentication. Which infers that they're probably using Spring MVC for the web framework.

So, Java with Spring stack is my guess, however I'm not sure if that's your question.

What it's written in should be largely immaterial in this context. If you don't know much about creating websites and you are wishing for a website like this one, it's probably best you just flick it onto a web designer and let them sort it out.

Comment: Cheers for the 2 answers so far. Yes you are right. I dont know enough about creating websites but I know enough to explain what I want to a designer. At least now I have some background on what platform  givenow may be running. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem. Again, I'd focus on what features of the website you would like on yours, rather than what the platform is. Any number of platforms could generate that site, which is possibly why your question was down-voted.

Answer (score -1):

On the first glance it looks like it's written in JavaScript only taking in account what I can see from the HTML-Sourcecode. What or if there is useded a server-sided programming language that couldn't even tell my cristal ball or my fortune teller but if you were even interested in how websites work (without any details on html, css, javasript or such) you could have found this out on your onw by asking Dr. Google or even Wikipedia would have provided you with a desent answer.

Comment: Thanks wolf. I looked at the source code and sort of made an assumption of what its written in etc.